# How to handle specific HttpClient errors

Tags: c#, .net-core

When the `HttpClient` throws an exception trying to get a page it returns a `HttpRequestException`.  This exception doesn't really have anything to categorize the error apart from the message so the only way i can see to handle errors is like so:

```cs
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.example.com/");
    // ...
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    if(e.Message == "Name or service not known")
    {
       HandleNotKnown();
       return;
    }
    
    if(e.Message == "Some other specific message")
    {
       HandleOtherError();
       return;
    }
    
    // ... etc
}
```

I don't like doing this because I feel like at some point the error text could change in an update and break my code.

Is there a better way to handle specific errors with HttpClient?

Comment: according to [docs, it should have InnerException property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netcore-3.1#System_Exception_InnerException)

Comment: Ah I see it now, the inner exception has a different exception type, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HttpRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception?view=netcore-3.1) inherits from Exception and so it has the InnerException property

[image]

```
Gets the Exception instance that caused the current exception.
```

So check this Exception for more details.